# Can't add to linked list in switch

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, switch-statement

I tested my class member function to add to a linked list outside of my switch and it works. But when I try to use it in my switch, it doesn't. It won't actually add to the list cause when I display the list nothing is there.

Class and implementation:

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class LinkedList{
        template<typename T>
        class Node
        {
        public:
                Node(T value = 0) : data(value), nextptr(NULL){};
                T retrieve() const{ return data; }
                Node<T> *next() const{ return nextptr; }
        private:
                T data;
                Node<T> *nextptr;
                friend LinkedList<T>;
        };
public:
        LinkedList();
        LinkedList(const T& x); //Copy Constructor
        ~LinkedList();
        void DisplayList();
        void ReverseList();
        LinkedList<T> operator= (const LinkedList<T> & x); //Assignment Operator
        bool isEmpty() const{ return Size() == 0; }
        int Size() const{ return n; }
        bool ElementAt(int k, T& x) const;
        LinkedList<T>& RemoveAt(int k, T& x)
        {
                if (k < 0 || k >= Size())
                {
                        cout << "Index not in list.";
                }

                Node<T> *del = NULL;
                if (k == 0)
                {
                        del = list_head;
                        list_head = del->nextptr;
                }
                else
                {
                        Node<T> *prev = list_head;
                        del = list_head->nextptr;
                        for (int i = 1; i< k; i++)
                        {
                                prev = del;
                                del = del->nextptr;
                        }
                        prev->nextptr = del->nextptr;
                }
                n--; x = del->data; delete del;
                return *this;
        }

        LinkedList<T>& Add(const T& x)
        {
                Node<T>
                        *node = new Node<T>(x);
                if (Size() == 0)
                        list_head = node;
                else
                {
                        Node<T> *temp = list_head;
                        while (temp->nextptr)
                        {
                                temp = temp->nextptr;
                        }
                        temp->nextptr = node;
                }
                n++;
                return *this;
        }


private:
        Node<T> *list_head;
        int n;
};

//Constructor
template<class T>
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList()
{
        list_head = NULL;
        n = 0;
}

//Copy Constructor
template<class T>
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList(const T& x)
{
        list_head = x.listhead;
        n = x.n;
}

//Destructor
template<class T>
LinkedList<T>::~LinkedList()
{
        Node<T> *temp = list_head, *del, *nextptr;

        while (temp != NULL)
        {
                del = temp->nextptr;
                delete temp;
                temp = del;
        }
}

template<class T>
bool LinkedList<T>::ElementAt(int k, T& x) const
{
        if (k < 0 || k >= Size())
                return false;

        Node<T> *temp = list_head;

        for (int i = 0; i< k; i++)
        {
                temp = temp->next;
        }
        x = temp->data;
        return true;
}

// Assignment Operator
template<class T>
LinkedList<T> LinkedList<T>::operator=(const LinkedList<T> & x)
{
        list_head = x.list_head;
        n = x.n;

        return *this;
}

template<class T>
void LinkedList<T>::DisplayList()
{
        Node<T> *temp = list_head;

        while (temp != NULL)
        {
                cout << temp->data << endl;
                temp = temp->nextptr;
        }
}

template<class T>
void LinkedList<T>::ReverseList()
{
        Node<T> *t, *y = list_head, *r = NULL, *listhead;

        while (y != NULL)
        {
                t = y->nextptr;
                y->nextptr = r;
                r = y;
                y = t;
        }
        list_head = r;
}

#endif
```

Driver:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Header.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
        int choice;
        string item;
        do
        {
                LinkedList<string> list;


                int num;

                cout << "1. Add new record to the file" << endl;
                cout << "2. Delete a record in the file (by index)" << endl;
                cout << "3. Display entire list of items" << endl;
                cout << "4. Display entire list of items backwards" << endl;
                cout << "5. Exit" << endl;
                cin >> choice;

                switch (choice)
                {
                case 1:
                {
                                  cout << "1. Add new record to the file" << endl;
                                  cout << "Enter the Item Description:" << endl;
                                  cin.ignore();
                                  getline(cin, item);
                                  list.Add(item);
                }
                        break;
                case 2:
                {
                                  cout << "2. Delete a record in the file" << endl;
                                  cout << "Enter the index number of the item you want to delete" << endl;
                                  cin >> num;
                                  //list.RemoveAt(num);
                }
                        break;
                case 3:
                {
                                  cout << "3. Display entire list of items" << endl;
                                  list.DisplayList();
                }
                        break;
                case 4:
                {
                                  cout << "4. Display entire list of items backwards" << endl;
                                  list.ReverseList();
                                  list.DisplayList();
                                  list.ReverseList();
                }
                        break;
                case 5:
                {
                                  return 0;
                }
                        break;
                }
        } while (0 < choice < 6);


        return 0;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the `cout` text inside the switch case get printed to the screen? If so, the switch case does trigger and it being inside a switch statement doesn't matter. You should add the **exact** sequence of calls outside the switch, which should reproduce it. Then you should make the code less by removing code that isn't being called. Then you should hardcode input so the program can just be run without needing to provide input. And you should show desired versus actual output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your `list` declaration outside of your `do..while` loop. At the moment it is being reinitialized each time round the loop.

Comment: omg. this isn't my first time doing this. I'm so ashamed. thanks bro<3